# Syncing my master branch with local developer sandbox

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, git

I tried checking out master branch and ran the following command in vscode `sfdx force:source:deploy -u Sandbox -p force-app/main/default -l RunLocalTests`

After that also i don't think master branch changes are synced with my sandbox. Is there anything i'm missing?

Comment: Do you get an error? If so please [edit] your question to add the exact message.

Comment: No i dint get any error message, but when i try to retrieve a file it shows old changes

Comment: Are you sure the file you are trying to retrieve is in the `force-app/main/default` folder structure? Is there a specific reason you are not using `force:source:push`?